# Switch map: how to map enum to value without switch

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

Let's say I want to convert an enum to another value:

```
enum MyEnum {

    case a
    case b
    case c

}

let myEnum: MyEnum = .a

let string: String
switch myEnum {
case .a:
    string = "a-string"
case .b:
    string = "b-string"
case .c
    string = "c-string"
}
```

in this example I'm converting `MyEnum` to `String` (but could be other types).

Now, it forced me to have that ugly `switch` and repeat the assignment operation `string =` for each `case`.

What I really want is something like this:

```
let string = switchMap(myEnum, [
    (.a, "a-string"),
    (.b, "b-string"),
    (.c, "c-string")
])
```

They I thought of implementing it was something like this:

```
func switchMap<V, R>(_ value: V, _ patterns: [(V, R)]) -> R? {
    for (k, v) in patterns {
        switch value {
        case k:
            return v
        default: ()
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

But this gives me the error `Expression pattern of type 'V' cannot match values of type 'V'`.

Any idea how to solve this? Maybe in a better way? (Ideally I'm looking for something that resembles Haskell's pattern matching, in terms os syntax).

I'm also looking for something that replaces the `swift` statement, so I want my input to accept any pattern that a `switch` would accept.

Obs.: I know, this solution also ain't perfect, since it returns `R?` instead of `R`, but I don't think I can do better than that, since `switch` relies on the compiler to know it's exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign rawValues to the cases:

```
enum MyEnum : String {

    case a = "a"
    case b = "b"
    case c = "c"

}
```

Then just access the string value with a.rawValue etc.

Comment: The question hints that the requirement may be to map the enum to different types, not just `String`.

Comment: @rmaddy fair point. My answer only works if all cases in the enum have the same type and so raw values can be used. Yours works for associated values too.

Comment: Exactly what @rmaddy said

Comment: Yes, I was thanking him for his input, hence I used his tag in the comment!